Run a calback when transection is confirmed in solana Blink
i want to send an email whenever a transection succeed in solana Blink.Is there any call back that we can run based on if the transection failed od succeed in Blink.

To send an email whenever a transaction succeeds or fails on Solana Blink, you can utilize a combination of Blink's callback functionality and an email service provider like SendGrid or Mailgun. Here's a general outline of the steps:
Step 1: Set up an email service provider
Choose an email service provider like SendGrid or Mailgun, and create an account. You'll need to obtain an API key or credentials to send emails programmatically.
Step 2: Configure a callback function in Blink
In Blink, you can set up a callback function to run after a transaction is processed. This callback function will be responsible for sending the email. You can configure the callback function in Blink using the  callback parameter when creating a new transaction.
Here's an example of how you can configure a callback function in Blink:
const blink = require('@blinklabs/blink');

async function sendTransaction() {
  const tx = await blink.sendTransaction({
    // Transaction details...
  }, {
    callback: async (txHash, txStatus) => {
      // This callback function will be executed after the transaction is processed
      if (txStatus === 'success') {
        sendEmail('Transaction succeeded!', txHash);
      } else {
        sendEmail('Transaction failed!', txHash);
      }
    }
  });
}

sendTransaction();

In this example, the callback function is called with the txHash and txStatus parameters. Based on the txStatus, you can send a success or failure email.
Step 3: Implement the email sending function
Create a separate function sendEmail that will send an email using your chosen email service provider. You can use a library like nodemailer to interact with your email service provider.
Here's an example implementation of the sendEmail function:
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

async function sendEmail(subject, txHash) {
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'your-email-service-provider.com',
    port: 587,
    auth: {
      user: 'your-email-address',
      pass: 'your-email-password'
    }
  });

  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'your-email-address',
    to: 'recipient-email-address',
    subject: subject,
    text: `Transaction ${txHash} has been ${subject.toLowerCase()}.`
  };

  try {
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.log('Email sent successfully!');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending email:', error);
  }
}

Putting it all together
Now, when you create a new transaction in Blink, you can pass the callback function to send an email based on the transaction status.
Here's the complete example:
const blink = require('@blinklabs/blink');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

async function sendTransaction() {
  const tx = await blink.sendTransaction({
    // Transaction details...
  }, {
    callback: async (txHash, txStatus) => {
      if (txStatus === 'success') {
        sendEmail('Transaction succeeded!', txHash);
      } else {
        sendEmail('Transaction failed!', txHash);
      }
    }
  });
}

async function sendEmail(subject, txHash) {
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'your-email-service-provider.com',
    port: 587,
    auth: {
      user: 'your-email-address',
      pass: 'your-email-password'
    }
  });

  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'your-email-address',
    to: 'recipient-email-address',
    subject: subject,
    text: `Transaction ${txHash} has been ${subject.toLowerCase()}.`
  };

  try {
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.log('Email sent successfully!');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending email:', error);
  }
}

sendTransaction();

This should give you a basic understanding of how to send an email whenever a transaction succeeds or fails on Solana Blink using callback functions.

blink.sendTransaction() , this does not exist in the blink library
